# How do i show that $\{m/2^n:m,n\in\mathbb{R}\}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis

How do i show that $\{m/2^n:m,n\in\mathbb{R}\}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$?

What would be an idea?

Comment: Are you sure $m,n\in\Bbb{R}?$ In such a case take $n=0$ and you have done.

Comment: Expand real numbers in base 2.

Comment: You need to show that for any real number $x$, and $\epsilon > 0$, there are $m,n$ such that $|x - m/2^n| < \epsilon$

Comment: @KajHansen Actually that property is true for $\mathbb{Z}$ that is not dense. What you need to show is that between two arbitrary points in $\mathbb{R}$ there will always be a point of the set.

Comment: As written, the set is *equal* to $\Bbb R$. Re we sure about the wording here?

Comment: The question is basically asking if you know what "dense" means, and what $\mathbb{R}$ is. In other words, if you understand the question, then you can answer it.

Answer (score 10):

As pointed out in the comments the question is trivial as posed now, but if you want to show (what I think you meant) that
$$
\left\{\frac{m}{2^n} \Bigm| m,n \in \mathbb{Z}\right\}
$$
is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ then let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ where $a < b$. The idea here is to first expand the interval $[a,b]$ so be at least $1$ unit of length long and the collapsing that interval back down. We know that $\exists n \in \mathbb{Z}$ so that
$$
(b-a)2^n > 1 \qquad (1)
$$
thus we know that there is an $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ so that $m \in [a 2^n, b 2^n]$ (since the interval is of length greater than $1$). Now we have
$$
a2^n < m < b2^n \implies a < \frac{m}{2^n} < b \qquad (2)
$$
If you want specific values of $m,n$ in terms of $a,b$ then consider
$$
n = \left\lfloor \log_2 \left( \frac{1}{b-a} \right) \right\rfloor + 1 
$$
so that we have $(1)$ (since $x < \lfloor x \rfloor + 1$). Then put
$$
m = \lfloor b 2^n \rfloor
$$
so that with $(1)$ (and the fact that $x - 1< \lfloor x \rfloor$) we have
$$
a 2^n < m \le b2^n
$$
and of course if $b = \frac{m}{2^n}$ we're done, otherwise we indeed have $(2)$ thus we're done as well.

Answer (score 2):

I think that it should be $\{ \frac{m}{2^n} :m \in \mathbb{Z}, n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$.

Let $(a,b) \subset \mathbb{R}$ where $a<b$ be an open segment in $\mathbb{R}$. Then exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|b-a|<\frac{1}{2^n}$. Divide $\mathbb{R}$ to subintervals $\mathbb{R}=\cup_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}[\frac{m}{2^n},\frac{m+1}{2^n})$. Then exists segment from this sum that its endpoint lay in $(a,b)$, because $(a,b)$ is shorter than each.

Comment: It's not true that $|b-a|<\frac{1}{2^n}$: take $a=0$ and $b=10$ for instance.

Comment: Ok, for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: You should also replace $|b-a|<1/2^n$ by $1/2^n<|b-a|$.

Answer (score 2):

I just give you the idea.

First: As noted in the comments above I assume that you are considering the set
$$
\left\{\frac{m}{2^n} : n,m \in \mathbb{Z}\right\}.
$$

Let $\epsilon >0$ be given. Let $x$ (reduced expression) be a rational number.

Now first pick $n$ such that

$$\frac{1}{2^n} < \epsilon/2.$$

That mans that for all $x\in \mathbb{Q}$ there is a $y\in  \mathbb{Z}\frac{1}{2^n} \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$ such that $\lvert x - y\rvert < \epsilon$.

Hence your set is dense in $\mathbb{Q}$. And $\mathbb{Q}$ is ...

Comment: I never thought of showing this sort of problem this way, very nice!

Comment: @Thomas, Why is the $\varepsilon$ necessary? Can't you just say that since $\forall n>0,  2^n \in \mathbb{Z} , $and $\frac{m}{2^n} \in \mathbb{Q}$  and $\forall n>0, \, m*2^n \in \mathbb{Q} $  and since $\mathbb{Q} $ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ then we're good?